# Implementing move semantics in the legacy C++ class

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am working on a legacy application with a class named `Point3D` as shown below...

```
template <class T>
class Point3D final
{
    T values[3];
public:
    Point3D();
    Point3D(T x, T y, T z);
    explicit Point3D(const T value);
    Point3D(const Point3D& point);
    explicit Point3D(const Point2D<T>& point);
    ~Point3D();
};
```

This class is getting used in many places as `vector<Point3D<double>>`. The size of the vector is > `10^5`.
Also, the legacy code passes this vector as a value and returns by value. This is making the application very slow.
Also in many places, we have similar codes as shown below...

```
for(auto i: n){ // This loop runs for 10^4 times
    Point3D<double> vpos;

    vpos[X_COORDINATE] = /*Some calculation*/;
    vpos[Y_COORDINATE] = /*Some calculation*/;
    vpos[Z_COORDINATE] = /*Some calculation*/;

    Positions.push_back(vpos);
}
```

To improve the performance, I plan to modify the `Point3D` class to use `move semantics` as shown below...

```
template <class T> 
class Point3D final {
    T* values;
public:
    Point3D() {
        values = new T[3];
    }
    Point3D(T x, T y, T z) {
        values = new T[3];
    }
    explicit Point3D(const T value) {
        values = new T[3];
        
    }
    Point3D(const Point3D& point) {
        values = new T[3];
    }
    ~Point3D() {
        delete[] values;
    }

    T  operator [] (qint64 coordinate) const { return values[coordinate]; }
    T& operator [] (qint64 coordinate) { return values[coordinate]; }

    Point3D& operator = (const Point3D& point) {
        ...
        return *this;
    }

    Point3D(Point3D&& other) noexcept : values(other.values)
    {
        other.values = nullptr;
    }

    Point3D& operator=(Point3D&& other) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I am new to `move semantics`, please let me know any other ways to improve the performance.
Thanks

Comment: no elements have to be moved to move a `std::vector`. Moving a `std::vector` is just copying an internal pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure all those small allocations are gonna be conducive to good performance.

Comment: I would bet a lot that the performance hit of moving to dynamic allocations for each point object will hurt performance orders of magnitude more than gains you could hope to get from making moves faster. Move might also be slower now, since you need to set 2 pointers on move. With the original version a copy it might be optimized to the equivalent of a single memcpy.

Comment: You make your program much slower with memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also, the legacy code passes this vector as a value and returns by value. This is making the application very slow.

Your suggested modifications will make this worse in general. The cost of copying or moving your original `Point3D` is very small if `T` is a simple type like `double`. It will just copy three `double` values. If `T` is a complex type, then as the other answer suggests, *removing* the declared destructor and copy constructor will cause move semantics to be implemented correctly *automatically*. (This is also known as the "*rule-of-zero*", letting all special member functions be implemented implicitly.)

If your problem are many copies of a vector of the type, move semantics on the type will however not help you at all. Copying the vector will still require *copying* all elements. Moving will not be sufficient.

You need to adjust your code at the use site of these vectors. For example, if you are passing a vector like this by-value:

```
void f(vector<Point3D<double>>);

void g() {
    vector<Point3D<double>> v;
    // fill v
    f(v);
}
```

Then this will make an unnecessary copy of the vector. It is unnecessary because `v`'s data is not required anymore after the call to `f` in `g`. So it can be *moved* instead of copied into the function:

```
void g() {
    vector<Point3D<double>> v;
    // fill v
    f(std::move(v));
}
```

This will move the *vector*, not the `Point3D<double>`'s. Moving a vector is a constant time operation, no matter whether or not move semantics are implemented for the element type. It won't copy or move any element.

If however `v`'s state is used in `g` after the call, then you *can't* use move semantics directly, because move semantics will cause the state to be lost. In that case you need to rethink the design of the function and consider e.g. passing by `const`-reference instead.

(Note however that you should *not* use `std::move` if you *return* the vector. E.g. `return std::move(v);` should be `return v;` instead. Move is implicit on return statements that just return a local variable directly by name and doing the implicit `std::move` call will inhibit copy elision which in certain situations will eliminate copy/moves completely.)

Answer (score 2):

The move constructor and assignment of `std::vector` *don't care* about the contained type, so you don't need to change your class at all. What you need to do is fix your use of `std::vector`.

You don't need to use dynamic allocations here, and you can gain move semantics by *removing* code. However there is nothing to gain from moving `double`s, you would only benefit using `Point3D<std::string>` or similar.

```
template <class T>
class Point3D final
{
    T values[3];
public:
    Point3D();
    Point3D(T x, T y, T z);
    explicit Point3D(const T value);
    explicit Point3D(const Point2D<T>& point);
};
```

Because you had specified a copy constructor, no move constructor was defaulted for your type. The defaults would do the correct thing, so you [don't need to specify](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) the special member functions.

Comment: `T` is a `double`, as stated in the question. As such, default move semantics will do bupkis here. It's true that the proposed approach might eke out something, but I doubt it. Exchanging the copying of three doubles for `new`/`delete` and extra memory references, non linear, plus reference counting, doesn't sound like much of a win.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in the example you showed you can simply replace the push_back by an emplace_back as follows:

```
Positions.reserve(10000);
for(auto i : n)
{ // This loop runs for 10^4 times
    auto x_coord = /*Some calculation*/;
    auto y_coord = /*Some calculation*/;
    auto z_coord = /*Some calculation*/;

    Positions.emplace_back(x_coord,y_coord,z_coord);
}
```

This constructs the Point3D instance in place so no move or copy has to be done.

I would suggest you to use std::array instead of a c style array for more modern c++. Also then you can use the default move and copy constructor and do not have to explicitly move or copy every element in the array. The Point3D class could then look as follows:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T> 
class Point3D  
{ 
     std::array<T,3> values;
public:
    Point3D()= default;
    Point3D(const T& x, const T& y, const T& z):
    values{x,y,z}
    {}

    // Rest of Class ...
    
};
```